# Cannot get bitmap size of a webP image that has transparency?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, webp, image-size

i'm making some experiments with the relatively new [**webP**](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/) image format , that is supported on android 4 (ICS) as shown [**here**](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) .

so far , in order to get the image size before loading it , i used the next code (similar to what google shows [**here**](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)) :

```
final BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds=true;
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream,null,options);
//image size is in options.outWidth,options.outHeight
```

however , when i use it on a webP image that has transparency , it seems that it can't get this info at all (returns -1 for both width and height) .

is it possible that google has a bug on decoding this image file type ?

is there a way to overcome this?

in order to test it , just convert a png file that has transparency (like [**this**](http://www.droidforums.net/forum/attachments/droid-news/50527d1338401753-someone-spilled-beans-googles-nexus-tablet-get-gimbals-jellybeans-pile.jpg) one that i've used and added some transparent pixels via [**paint.net**](http://www.getpaint.net/) app ) to a webP format (using [**google's tool**](https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/download) ), and try to read the resolution of the file like the code i've used.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue as well.

Sadly, according to this [bug report](https://code.google.com/p/webp/issues/detail?id=147) support for WEBP with transparency was only added in Android JB-MR2 (4.2).

So in android 4.0 until 4.2 WEBP only works if there's no alpha channel.

Comment: do you know of a library that can decode&encode webP files? that would be great and remove the need for android version compatibility .

Comment: As far as I know there's only the native route. Explained in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8422707/970993). But I think you cannot use for example Bitmap options like inJustDecodeBounds then. Personally I'm just serving webp to android 4.2+, which will be a growing target anyway. But a support library for this would be great.

Comment: looks like a lot of work , and that's only for simple decoding, after you got the whole byte array. it might also not be efficient as you need to load the entire byte array before decoding.